# How do you compare and return duplicates in two different 2d list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, 2d

I would like to return the duplicates in two different 2d lists. But I'm having trouble figuring out what code to write. For example I would like variable "a" to compare to variable "b" and return the duplicates. Here are my two 2d list below.

```
a = [[2,3,6,8],[4,5,7,8,10],[15,17,21,22],[12,13,14,23,25]]
b = [[4,5,6],[15,17,21,22],[2,3,4],[2,3,6,8],[5,7,8,12,15],[7,12,14,17,32],[5,6,7,12,14]]
```

I would like my results to be:

```
c = [[2,3,6,8],[15,17,21,22]]
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I havent tried no code because i dont know what code to write

Comment: Then you are not yet ready for a question here.

Comment: Also every question you've asked seems to be about this, and you've had answers; how do you have no progress to show?

Comment: Here's a hint, looking at what you want your result to be, it appears the fact that your two lists are 2D is irrelevant. So it might be simpler for you to just think about how you'd return duplicated elements from two 1D lists (it just so happens that each element in these lists are themselves lists).

Comment: I really dont know what code to write. Im sorry i am kind of new to python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check if a list in `a` is also in `b` or not.

```
a = [[2,3,6,8],[4,5,7,8,10],[15,17,21,22],[12,13,14,23,25]]
b = [[4,5,6],[15,17,21,22],[2,3,4],[2,3,6,8],[5,7,8,12,15],[7,12,14,17,32],[5,6,7,12,14]]
c=[]
for i in a:
    if i in b:
        c.append(i)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3, 6, 8], [15, 17, 21, 22]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, it should get you started -

```
import itertools

#Input lists
a = [[2,3,6,8],[4,5,7,8,10],[15,17,21,22],[12,13,14,23,25]]
b = [[4,5,6],[15,17,21,22],[2,3,4],[2,3,6,8],[5,7,8,12,15],[7,12,14,17,32],[5,6,7,12,14]]

#Take a product of both the lists ( a X b )
z = itertools.product(a,b)

#Uncomment the following to see what itertools.product does
#[i for i in z]

#Return only the elements which the pair of the same element repeats (using string match)
[i[0] for i in z if str(i[0])==str(i[1])]
```

```
[[2, 3, 6, 8], [15, 17, 21, 22]]
```

Comment: anytime buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = [[2,3,6,8],[4,5,7,8,10],[15,17,21,22],[12,13,14,23,25]]
b = [[4,5,6],[15,17,21,22],[2,3,4],[2,3,6,8],[5,7,8,12,15],[7,12,14,17,32],[5,6,7,12,14]]
c = []
for i in a + b: 
    if (a + b).count(i) > 1 and i not in c:
        c.append(i)
```

@mulaixi's answer is OK but in output list you may see duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

one liner list comprehension approach:

```
dups = [i for i in a if i in b]
```

output:

```
[[2, 3, 6, 8], [15, 17, 21, 22]]
```